# Bootstrap Collapsible is not closing

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a html file, where I have a collapsible section. I have used bootstrap collapsible to collapse a div. When I click on the collapse icon, it triggers the animation and it the div closes, but, again the div opens again. I can see that from inspect view, the When I click on the 'show' class is removed from the div.

When I click on the collapse icon again, it triggers the animation to open, and the div is shown again. Now, the 'show' class is added back.

But, closing the div is not working. Could you please point out the error?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Report</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-offset="50">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="TestOverview">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <h3 class="text-center">Test Overview</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="test">
        <div id="testCasesOverview" style="text-align: center">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="alert-warning ">
                <td>
                  <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#_1_Suite2" id="1_Suite2" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size: 1.4em; display: none;" id="on1_Suite2"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 1.4em; display: block;" id="off1_Suite2"></i>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col-11" style="text-align:left;"><a class="nav-link" href="#Suite2">1_Suite2</a></td>
                <td class="col-3">PASS</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <div id="_1_Suite2" class="collapse show" style="">
            <table id="1_Suite2_TestUnit" class="_1_Suite2 collapse">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="background:#AFB9F0;">
                  <td>
                    <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="._1_Suite2_TestUnit">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size:1.4em" id="on1_Suite2_TestUnit"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size:1.4em;display: none" id="off1_Suite2_TestUnit"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-4">1_Suite2_TestUnit</td>
                  <td class="col-2" style="background:#00FF33">PASS</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Report</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-offset="50">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="TestOverview">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <h3 class="text-center">Test Overview</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="test">
        <div id="testCasesOverview" style="text-align: center">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="alert-warning ">
                <td>
                  <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#_1_Suite2" id="1_Suite2" aria-expanded="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size: 1.4em; display: none;" id="on1_Suite2"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 1.4em; display: block;" id="off1_Suite2"></i>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col-11" style="text-align:left;"><a class="nav-link" href="#Suite2">1_Suite2</a></td>
                <td class="col-3">PASS</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <div id="_1_Suite2" class="collapse show" style="">
            <table id="1_Suite2_TestUnit" class="_1_Suite2 collapse">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="background:#AFB9F0;">
                  <td>
                    <a class="btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="._1_Suite2_TestUnit">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" style="font-size:1.4em" id="on1_Suite2_TestUnit"></i>
                      <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size:1.4em;display: none" id="off1_Suite2_TestUnit"></i>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td class="col-4">1_Suite2_TestUnit</td>
                  <td class="col-2" style="background:#00FF33">PASS</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Attached the below picture for more demo purpose.

[image]

Thanks,
Pal.